# How can I capture the center portion of an uploaded image? (to make a thumbnail)

Tags: php, image, upload

I have to handle the images uploaded by users and want to make thumbnails out of them, in order to create an image gallery.

The problem is that the images uploaded by the user differ in dimensions, so constraining the dimensions of the thumbnail will make disproportioned images as thumbnails.

Do you know how I can capture the center portion (or truncate the sides) of an uploaded image? Or do you know any script that will handle that?

Thanks a lot

Regards

EDIT:

```
echo '<div class="pic" style="background-image: url(upload/photos/'.$photo1.')"></div>';
```

and

```
    .pic {

    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cropping the images, you can also use a normal resized thumbnail that is big enough to fit the box you want it for completely, and set it as a background image.

So if your box is 100x100 pixels, your thumbnail images need to be resized to 100px width for a vertical image and 100px height for a horizontal image.

By the way, for modern browsers you can use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

So that the image completely covers the box, maintaining its aspect ratio.

**Edit:** So in your php you would do something like:

```
echo '<div style="background-image: url(' . $path_to_image . ');"></div>';
```

and in the css:

```
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I will try that and let you know. Regards

Comment: Hi, I used something similar to what you suggested. I wrapped the images into div's, set height and width, and used the property overflow:hidden. But the problem is I see the top left corner of the image. Do you know how to put the center of the image at the center of the div? thanks a lot

Comment: @alexx0186 There are perhaps tricks to achieve that with javascript, but it is so much easier with a background image... Why don't you want to use a background image?

Comment: You mean a background-image using CSS? Is that the url(path/image.jpg) property? Am I supposed to change that "image.jpg" dynamically? I didn't know it was possible.

Comment: My concern is the old browsers, if I use background-size. So would you suggest javascript for compatibility purposes?

Comment: @alexx0186 I have added an example.

Comment: @alexx0186 No problem with old browsers if you use a resized thumbnail image, background-size will have no effect. It will not have any effect anyway if your thumnails have the exact width or height of the box.

Comment: I don't know, maybe someone else disagreed, because I accepted your answer. I put my code in Edit in my original post. For some reason nothing appears on my page. Not sure if I mistyped anything.. Thanks a lot

Comment: *A downvote, really? Would be nice to add an explanation.* We can explain many things in the world of coding, but I think this will be a mystery for every why you got a downvote here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find my written script in my github repository. Here you are, test it and let me know.

URL: https://github.com/armpogart/Examples/blob/master/crop_resize/crop.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am looking into your script. regards

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

It takes a filename and retunrs an array containg the image information.

Then you can spot the center of the image with something like:

```
$image_info = getimagesize( $filename );
$width = $image_info[0];
$height = $image_info[1];    
$center = array($width/2,$height/2);

// continue proccessing your image //
```

You can also check for the dimensions and decide whether you want your image to be cropped or not. using `print_r($image_info)`; will help you.

Good luck.